# Javascript shows a different effect when run in localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is wrong with the code guys. I have a problem running this on a localhost. the `getModuleData()` is called when the user triggers an onclick event. the module_list div is hidden at first load of the page and lastSelectedModule is set to -1. Now when the user click the click me button it will call the `getModuleData()`. The problem is when i click the button it load the new data first then fadeout then fadein again. What i really want to happen is fadeout the old data then fadein the new data. i have try tracing it using console.log(); but the output is.

Not Ajax

Ajax

Not Ajax

Ajax

***html***

some code

`<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick = 'getModuleData(sampleIdid)'><span>Click me</span>`

```
<div id ="module_list"> 
      <div id ="module_content">

      </div>
</div>
```

***javascript***

```
function getModuleData(id)
{ 
    if(lastSelectedModule === -1){
       var off_set = $('#circular_navigation').offset().top;
       $('#module_list').show(1000,null);
       $('#hr_blue').show();
       animateScroll(off_set,800); 
    }

    if (lastSelectedModule !== id)
    {  
    console.log("Not Ajax");
    $('#module_content').fadeOut(1000,'',null);
    $('#loading').fadeIn(); 
    $('#module_icon_'+lastSelectedModule).removeAttr('style'); 
    document.getElementById('module_icon_'+id).style.cssText = '-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #1589FF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #1589FF;  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1589FF;';

        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: 'getModuleById.php',
              data: "module_id=" + id,  
              success: function(data) { 
              $('#loading').hide(); 
              $('#module_content').fadeIn(1000,null).html(data); 
              var targetOffset = $("#"+id).offset().top  - $('#circular_navigation').outerHeight(true); 
              animateScroll(targetOffset,800); 
                      console.log("Ajax");
            }
        }); 
        lastSelectedModule = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qaqjt/2/)**</kbd>

You can use callback parameter of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods to do something right after effect. So, the correct way to do what you want is to fade element out and then change it and fade it in using callback. For example:

```
$('#module_content').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).html('Some new text').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/